# ¿Por qué no me muestra los parámetros disponibles para personalizar los estilos de seaborn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, seaborn

Estoy iniciando un tutorial de `seaborn` en jupyter notebook. Para personalizar los estilos de Seaborn, podemos pasar un diccionario de parámetros a la función `set_style ()`. Los parámetros disponibles deberiamos verlos usando la función `axes_style()`.

```
import seaborn as sb
print (sb.axes_style)
```

Me devuelve:  `<function axes_style at 0x7f691682ec10>`

Debería devolverme un diccionario.

```
{'axes.axisbelow'     : False,
'axes.edgecolor'      : 'white',
'axes.facecolor'      : '#EAEAF2',
'axes.grid'           : True,
'axes.labelcolor'     : '.15',
..............................
```

¿Cuál puede ser la causa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te está sucediendo es que no estás ejecutando la función. Para ejecutar una función en Python debes llamarla usando parentesis`()`. Por lo que deberías hacer:

```
import seaborn as sb
print(sb.axes_style())
```

Si no utilizas los parentesis, lo que haces es **pasarle una referencia de donde se encuentra almacenada la función en memoria**, por ello tu tienes `function axes_style at 0x7f691682ec10` que significa, que la función `axes_style` se encuentra almacenada en el espacio de memoria `0x7f691682ec10`

### Bonus

Esto no quiere decir que no tenga sentido pasar una función por referencia, de hecho el propio Python tiene funciones del lenguaje que es necesario hacerlo así, por ejemplo `map()`

```
numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def al_cuadrado(x):
    return x**2

list(map(al_cuadrado, numeros))
```

**Salida:**

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
```

En este caso `map` necesita que se le pase donde se encuentra almacenada la función para aplicarla.